# Which corner do UVs start in on default three.js planeGeometry?

Tags: three.js, uv-mapping

I'm writing a deformer which modifies the position of a plane's vertices, using UVs as a completion ratio – so if the UV of a vertex is (.5,.5), it's in the center of the plane.

An image linked from [(Three.js) Custom Mesh UV Display Texture Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798637/three-js-custom-mesh-uv-display-texture-properly) shows UVs starting in the top left:

[image]

But my deformer seems to be flipped vertically unless I treat the UVs as starting in the bottom left corner instead.

[OpenGL ES has different UV coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619584/opengl-es-has-different-uv-coordinates) says OpenGL UVs start in the bottom-left corner, and http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/154324/how-do-uvs-work.html suggests it's this way in Unity too. Which does three.js use?

Extra Credit: I understand from [Correct UV mapping Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891507/correct-uv-mapping-three-js) that the answer is in [planeGeometry.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/geometries/PlaneGeometry.js) somewhere – can anyone show where?

Comment: I've been assuming bottom-left corner is the origin for my coordinates and getting correct results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `THREE.PlaneGeometry`, UV `( 0, 0 )` is located at the bottom left, and `( 1, 1 )` the top right.

three.js r.64